# How to display total of values in the same table as a row (in case statement)?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, select

I have got a query:

```
SELECT t.diapason, COUNT(distinct user_id) AS 'number_of_users'
    FROM (SELECT p.user_id, p.amount as total, CASE  
       when amount<=100 then '0-100' 
       when amount>100 and amount<=150 then '100-150' 
       when amount>150 then '>150 +' END AS diapason
       FROM 
         (SELECT payments.user_id, SUM(amount) AS amount 
         FROM payments INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM activity 
          where login_time between '2018-04-12' and '2018-04-18') a ON 
          payments.user_id = a.user_id
          GROUP BY payments.user_id) p) t
GROUP BY t.diapason
ORDER BY number_of_users desc;
```

What should I change to display total of number_of_users as a row?

Output

```
+----------+-----------------+
| diapason | number_of_users |
+----------+-----------------+
| 0-100    |             278 |
| >150 +   |              16 |
| 100-150  |              12 |
| total    |             306 |    - I need this row
+----------+-----------------+
```

Thanks!

Comment: what is your sample data ?

Comment: You could union

Comment: Case _expression_. (Returns a value.)

Comment: I much nicer way of dealing with ranges in sql can be found https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/68791/group-by-in-ranges

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [ROLLUP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html), something like:

```
SELECT IF(GROUPING(t.diapason), 'total', t.diapason) AS diapason,
       COUNT(distinct user_id) AS 'number_of_users'
FROM (SELECT p.user_id, p.amount as total, CASE  
   when amount<=100 then '0-100' 
   when amount>100 and amount<=150 then '100-150' 
   when amount>150 then '>150 +' END AS diapason
   FROM 
     (SELECT payments.user_id, SUM(amount) AS amount 
     FROM payments INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM activity 
      where login_time between '2018-04-12' and '2018-04-18') a ON 
      payments.user_id = a.user_id
      GROUP BY payments.user_id) p) t
GROUP BY t.diapason WITH ROLLUP;
```

Comment: thanks! It works. But it displays:  NULL     |             306. How to change on "total' instead of word 'NULL'?

Comment: @ЕлисейГорьков updated my answer, check it out. Do not forget to accept it as the correct answer if it helped you. Happy coding! :)

Comment: ERROR 1221 (HY000): Incorrect usage of CUBE/ROLLUP and ORDER BY

Comment: thanks, but...ERROR 1305 (42000): FUNCTION businessanalysis.GROUPING does not exist

Comment: GROUPING function is new in MySQL 8.0.  See https://mysqlserverteam.com/mysql-8-0-grouping-function/

Answer (score 0):

There's already a good answer here but just in case you cannot use ROLLUP you can use UNION:

```
SELECT t.diapason, COUNT(distinct user_id) AS 'number_of_users'
    FROM (SELECT p.user_id, p.amount as total, CASE  
       when amount<=100 then '0-100' 
       when amount>100 and amount<=150 then '100-150' 
       when amount>150 then '>150 +' END AS diapason
       FROM 
         (SELECT payments.user_id, SUM(amount) AS amount 
         FROM payments INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM activity 
          where login_time between '2018-04-12' and '2018-04-18') a ON 
          payments.user_id = a.user_id
          GROUP BY payments.user_id) p) t
GROUP BY t.diapason
UNION ALL
SELECT 'total' AS diapason, COUNT(distinct user_id) AS 'number_of_users'
    FROM (SELECT p.user_id, p.amount as total, CASE  
       when amount<=100 then '0-100' 
       when amount>100 and amount<=150 then '100-150' 
       when amount>150 then '>150 +' END AS diapason
       FROM 
         (SELECT payments.user_id, SUM(amount) AS amount 
         FROM payments INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM activity 
          where login_time between '2018-04-12' and '2018-04-18') a ON 
          payments.user_id = a.user_id
          GROUP BY payments.user_id) p) t
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY number_of_users desc;
```

Hope it helps